# Why does Android M requires location permissions to scan Wifi

Tags: android-wifi, android-permissions

I realized that Android M requires at least one of `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions  to scan Wifi.

I don't think it's a *technical* issue but that there is a sort of *philosophical* reason (e.g., privacy) for such a weird policy.

But I couldn't find the exact reason for that and I would appreciate if someone give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of available Wifi networks for a device can be indeed used to locate the device.

To locate the device on needs the list of of the wifi networks the device can see and a `huge` database with known wifi networks and the position of the access points. With this information one can [triangulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation) the position of the phone.

Multiple of these `huge` databases exist. Apple, Google, etc. have each one and there are also public ones: http://www.openwlanmap.org/

Read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system